# Mongo db not able to compare only date in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to compare 2 date fields but it always compare with DateTime not only with Date value.
Below is a query

This is the property that used to store CreatedDate in DateTime format.

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

This is the query that I used to get counts with 2 date range.

```
var count = _baseIncomeRepositoryProperties.GetTotalCount(x => x.OrgId == request.OrganizationId && (x.CreatedDate >= request.StartDate.Date && x.CreatedDate <= request.EndDate.Date));
```

For Example below is the dates

```
CreatedDate = "15/02/22 1:23:43 AM"
StartDate = "15/02/22 12:00:00 AM"
EndDate = "15/02/22 12:00:00 AM"
```

When I try to execute the query it gives 0 count even if database has data.

Comment: 12:00:00 AM is the beginning of the day? so CreatedDate > EndDate.Date, so it should be 0 count.

Comment: I just want to compare the date only, is there any way?

Comment: NO it throws error property.Date is not supported

Comment: Perhaps you could assign `request.StartDate.Date` and `request.EndDate.Date` to a variable before using it in the query, so that it doesn't have to try and translate it into a Mongo query.

Comment: @Llama request.StartDate and request.EndDate both is already variable

Comment: Yes, but `request.StartDate.Date` isn't, so when the code runs to try and convert the expression into a Mongo query, it will try and convert the property access into a Mongo query, which it can't (as evidenced by the exception). That's why I said to assign the result of `request.StartDate.Date` to a variable, right?